# Resizing in interact.js

Tags: interact.js

I am trying to learn how to use the interact.js library and I cant get the resizing example to be draggable. I can resize the div ".resize-drag" but I don´t know how to get it draggable. Can anyone tell me is wrong with my code?

This code is only so that I can learn to implement the resize example provided at http://interactjs.io/ So far I´ve tried using npm instead of the script tag. When I copied the example below from the top of the interact.js website and renamed the element ".item" in the interact claus but that did not work

```
interact('.item').draggable({
onmove(event) {
console.log(event.pageX,
            event.pageY)
  }
})
```

I suspected it might be a syntax error so I also tried adding semicolon behind the function but that didn´t seem to be the problem. Please have a look at my entire code below to see what I have done wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .resize-drag {
  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 30px 20px;

  width: 120px;

  /* This makes things *much* easier */
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.resize-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
        </style>

        <script 
src="https://unpkg.com/interactjs@1.3.4/dist/interact.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">


    interact('.resize-drag').draggable({
    onmove(event) {
    console.log(event.pageX,
            event.pageY)
  }
})



    interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    onmove: window.dragMoveListener,
    restrict: {
      restriction: 'parent',
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },
  })


  .resizable({
    // resize from all edges and corners
    edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },

    // keep the edges inside the parent
    restrictEdges: {
      outer: 'parent',
      endOnly: true,
    },

    // minimum size
    restrictSize: {
      min: { width: 100, height: 50 },
    },

    inertia: true,
  })
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);

    // update the element's style
    target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

    // translate when resizing from top or left edges
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' +         
 Math.round(event.rect.height);
  });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="resize-container">
         <div class="resize-drag">
         Resize from any edge or corner
         </div>
   </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to drag the div and not just resize it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently struggled with that as well, and it turned out that the 'resizing' code blurbs don't have all the code. The js is missing window.dragMoveListener and dragMoveListener, which is found in the 'dragging' section.

Specifically you need to add this

```js
  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // this is used later in the resizing and gesture demos
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```